# When somone has two jobs, what is correct usage of 'indefinite article'?

Tags: indefinite-article

When somone has two jobs, what is correct usage of 'indefinite article'?

A. Jack Hamilton, **a** small business owner and **a** construction foreman, died yesterday. 
B. Jack Hamilton, **a** small business owner and construction foreman, died yesterday.

C. He is **a** doctor and **a** writer. 
D. He is **a** doctor and writer.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical. *A small business owner and construction foreman* is the more usual pattern in this context.